# $-0.1111\cdot5^{-11}$ from base 5 to base 10

Tags: number-systems

> Convert $-0.1111\cdot5^{-11}$ from base 5 to base 10.

My attempt:
$$-(5^{-12}+5^{-13}+5^{-14}+5^{-15})=5\cdot10^{-8}$$
But this is different from the given answer:
$$-1.59744\cdot10^{-5}$$

Comment: I just used this online calculator and looks like he's right http://wims.unice.fr/wims/en_tool~number~baseconv.en.html

Comment: sorry the 5 is I think a base

Comment: The _exponent_ is in base 5 itself (11 in base 5 to 6 in base 10).

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks everyone for the hints :)